# Android 11 tablet cannot connect to WiFi (saved; obtaining IP adrress)

Tags: wi-fi, networking, connection-issues, android-11

I got a new Thomson Teo 13.3 Android 11 tablet (I started from factory defaults, it is *brand new*). I made a new Wi-Fi network on my NETGEAR WAX202 router, let's call its SSID "MyNetwork2", and had this tablet connect to it. It spins under "obtaining IP address" for a while; and then says "Saved" and that's all it shows.

I have 5 devices on my home network connected to the same router, and they work without a problem - although they are connected to a different Wi-Fi network. To test, I had my LineageOS 17 Samsung smartphone connect to this "MyNetwork2" - no problem whatsoever. So it is not the router, I imagine.

I found that Android 11 introduced some changes that may break WiFi network connectivity. Some of the articles I read:

[Connecting Android 11+ devices to WPA/WPA2/WPA3/Enterprise SSID](https://www.ironwifi.com/help/connecting-android-11-devices-to-wpa-enteprise-secured-networks)

> Since Android 11 Security Enhancement released in December 2020, this has changed and as a result, you cannot skip the certificate validation.

[PSA: Android 11 will no longer let you insecurely connect to enterprise WiFi networks](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-11-break-enterprise-wifi-connection/)

> The problem that many users will come across after they update to Android 11* is that the "Do Not Validate" option under the "CA certificate" dropdown has been removed

Although that probably does not apply to me, because I do not use an enterprise network.

Eventually I also found:

[Wi-Fi connection issues with the Xiaomi Mi A2](https://tdb0.wordpress.com/2020/12/10/wi-fi-connection-issues-with-the-xiaomi-mi-a2/)

> he had enabled WPA alongside WPA2 on the AP. They also confirmed that this wasn’t something I could’ve done myself, as there is no relevant option in the "user-facing" part of the configuration panel. ...

> ... which in turn leads wpa_supplicant to ignore the fact that there’s a MBO/OCE tag (which is, of course, still present) despite the AP not supporting PMF as reported in the RSN IE, and just use the WPA IE to choose the needed ciphers

I don't understand half of the words here, but I tried disabling dual frequencies on the WiFi network, and adding both WPA and WPA2 - and of course, this didn't work either.

Anyways, I tried to obtain a logcat during the connection attempts, when the WiFi network is in this state:

[image: wax202-wifi-setup]

I tried to grep only for relevant stuff:

```
$ grep -i 'wifi\|wpa\|conn\|net' ~/Desktop/logcat2
06-29 10:24:30.387   413  4727 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:24:30.822   413  4727 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:24:31.852   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:34.867   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:35.820   413  4727 D WifiNl80211Manager: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:24:35.820   413  4727 D WifiNative: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:24:35.839   413   505 D WificondScannerImpl: Filtering out 2 scan results.
06-29 10:24:35.859   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:35.907  1020  1754 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
06-29 10:24:37.784   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:37.883  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=37:XX:XX:XX:XX:e2 reason=3 locally_generated=1
06-29 10:24:37.892   326   326 I wificond: Regulatory domain changed
06-29 10:24:37.893   413   433 I EthernetTracker: interfaceLinkStateChanged, iface: wlan0, up: false
06-29 10:24:37.898   326   326 I wificond: 2.4Ghz frequencies: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
06-29 10:24:37.901   326   326 I wificond: 5Ghz non-DFS frequencies:
06-29 10:24:37.901   326   326 I wificond: 5Ghz DFS frequencies:
06-29 10:24:37.901   326   326 I wificond: 6Ghz frequencies:
06-29 10:24:37.902   326   326 I wificond: Regulatory domain changed to country: ES
06-29 10:24:37.909   326   326 I wificond: 2.4Ghz frequencies: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
06-29 10:24:37.909   326   326 I wificond: 5Ghz non-DFS frequencies:
06-29 10:24:37.909   326   326 I wificond: 5Ghz DFS frequencies:
06-29 10:24:37.909   326   326 I wificond: 6Ghz frequencies:
06-29 10:24:37.920   413   501 W LastMileLogger: Failed to stop event tracing: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/instances/wifi/tracing_on: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-29 10:24:37.921   413   501 W LastMileLogger: Failed to read event trace: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/instances/wifi/trace
06-29 10:24:37.929  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
06-29 10:24:37.949  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=ES
06-29 10:24:37.952   413   501 D WifiCountryCode: Reading country code from telephony
06-29 10:24:37.963   413   501 D WifiCountryCode: Set telephony country code to: 
06-29 10:24:37.965   413   501 D WifiCountryCode: updateCountryCode to null
06-29 10:24:37.965   413   501 D WifiClientModeImpl: Start Disconnecting Watchdog 23
06-29 10:24:37.968   413   501 I WifiClientModeImpl: Keep PMK cache for network disconnection reason 3
06-29 10:24:37.969   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: stopRssiMonitoring(l.2100) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE, .description = }
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: stopIpClient IpClientWithPreConnection: false
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: java.lang.Throwable
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.stopIpClient(ClientModeImpl.java:1069)
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.stopDhcpSetup(ClientModeImpl.java:1084)
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.handleNetworkDisconnect(ClientModeImpl.java:2761)
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.access$5400(ClientModeImpl.java:163)
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl$ConnectModeState.processMessage(ClientModeImpl.java:4290)
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:992)
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:809)
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
06-29 10:24:37.975   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
06-29 10:24:37.977   413   506 D ConnectivityService: [122 WIFI] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from UNKNOWN to DISCONNECTED
06-29 10:24:37.977   413   506 D ConnectivityService: [122 WIFI] disconnected, was satisfying 0
06-29 10:24:37.997   413   501 I WifiClientModeImpl: disconnectedstate enter
06-29 10:24:37.999   413   501 E WifiScoringParams: Invalid frequency(-1), using 5G as default rssi array
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: stopIpClient IpClientWithPreConnection: false
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: java.lang.Throwable
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.stopIpClient(ClientModeImpl.java:1069)
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.access$4200(ClientModeImpl.java:163)
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl$DisconnectedState.processMessage(ClientModeImpl.java:5686)
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:992)
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:809)
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
06-29 10:24:38.006   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
06-29 10:24:38.009   413   501 I WifiClientModeImpl: Keep PMK cache for network disconnection reason 3
06-29 10:24:38.013   413   501 D WifiNetworkAgent: NetworkAgent: NetworkAgent channel lost
06-29 10:24:38.030   413   506 D ConnectivityService: NetReassign [no changes]
06-29 10:24:39.388   413  3531 D WifiNl80211Manager: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:24:39.388   413  3531 D WifiNative: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:24:39.431   413   505 D WificondScannerImpl: Filtering out 7 scan results.
06-29 10:24:39.447   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:39.475  1020  1754 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
06-29 10:24:40.391   413  4727 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:24:40.827   413  4727 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:24:41.776   413  4727 D WifiNl80211Manager: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:24:41.776   413  4727 D WifiNative: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:24:41.810   413   505 D WificondScannerImpl: Filtering out 4 scan results.
06-29 10:24:41.820   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:41.860  1020  1754 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
06-29 10:24:42.197   413  4727 I WifiService: connect uid=1000
06-29 10:24:42.208   413   501 D WifiConfigManager: Enable disabled network: "MyNetwork2" num=0
06-29 10:24:42.251   413   501 D WifiConfigStore: Writing to stores completed in 18 ms.
06-29 10:24:42.256   413   501 D WifiClientModeImpl: connectToUserSelectNetwork netId 5, uid 1000, forceReconnect = false
06-29 10:24:42.266   413   501 D WifiClientModeImpl: CMD_START_CONNECT  my state DisconnectedState nid=5 roam=false
06-29 10:24:42.310   413   501 D WifiClientModeImpl: No changes in MAC address
06-29 10:24:42.314   413   501 W LastMileLogger: Failed to open free_buffer pseudo-file: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/instances/wifi/free_buffer: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-29 10:24:42.316   413   501 I WifiClientModeImpl: Connecting with 7a:f8:f8:9e:da:fc as the mac address
06-29 10:24:42.317   326   326 W wificond: Scan is not started. Ignore abort request
06-29 10:24:42.319   413   501 D SupplicantStaIfaceHal: connectToNetwork "MyNetwork2"WPA_PSK
06-29 10:24:42.319   413   501 D SupplicantStaIfaceHal: Network is already saved, but need to update BSSID.
06-29 10:24:42.334  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 37:XX:XX:XX:XX:e2 (SSID='MyNetwork2' freq=2472 MHz)
06-29 10:24:42.454  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Trying to associate with 37:XX:XX:XX:XX:e2 (SSID='MyNetwork2' freq=2472 MHz)
06-29 10:24:42.560   413   433 I EthernetTracker: interfaceLinkStateChanged, iface: wlan0, up: true
06-29 10:24:42.563  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Associated with 37:XX:XX:XX:XX:e2
06-29 10:24:42.568  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: WPA: RX message 1 of 4-Way Handshake from 37:XX:XX:XX:XX:e2 (ver=2)
06-29 10:24:42.572  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: WPA: Sending EAPOL-Key 2/4
06-29 10:24:42.572  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
06-29 10:24:42.583  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: WPA: RX message 3 of 4-Way Handshake from 37:XX:XX:XX:XX:e2 (ver=2)
06-29 10:24:42.583  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: WPA: Sending EAPOL-Key 4/4
06-29 10:24:42.607  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 37:XX:XX:XX:XX:e2 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
06-29 10:24:42.607  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 37:XX:XX:XX:XX:e2 completed [id=0 id_str=%7B%22configKey%22%3A%22%5C%22MyNetwork2%5C%22WPA_PSK%22%2C%22creatorUid%22%3A%221000%22%7D]
06-29 10:24:42.612   413   433 I EthernetTracker: interfaceLinkStateChanged, iface: wlan0, up: true
06-29 10:24:42.629   413   501 D ConnectivityService: registerNetworkAgent NetworkAgentInfo{ ni{[type: WIFI[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: , failover: false, available: true, roaming: false]}  network{123}  nethandle{531686674445}  lp{{InterfaceName: wlan0 LinkAddresses: [ ] DnsAddresses: [ ] Domains: null MTU: 0 Routes: [ ]}}  nc{[ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps OwnerUid: 1000 SSID: "MyNetwork2" RequestorUid: -1 RequestorPackageName: null]}  Score{20}  everValidated{false}  lastValidated{false}  created{false} lingering{false} explicitlySelected{true} acceptUnvalidated{false} everCaptivePortalDetected{false} lastCaptivePortalDetected{false} partialConnectivity{false} acceptPartialConnectivity{false} clat{mBaseIface: null, mIface: null, mState: IDLE} }
06-29 10:24:42.663   413   506 D ConnectivityService: [123 WIFI] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: stopIpClient IpClientWithPreConnection: false
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: java.lang.Throwable
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.stopIpClient(ClientModeImpl.java:1069)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.stopDhcpSetup(ClientModeImpl.java:1084)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.startIpClient(ClientModeImpl.java:6535)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.access$6800(ClientModeImpl.java:163)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl$ObtainingIpState.enter(ClientModeImpl.java:5132)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.invokeEnterMethods(StateMachine.java:1037)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.performTransitions(StateMachine.java:879)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:819)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
06-29 10:24:42.680   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
06-29 10:24:42.693   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:42.717   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:42.741   413   506 D ConnectivityService: NetReassign [no changes]
06-29 10:24:42.756  3386  3386 E PreferenceGroup: Found duplicated key: "StandardWifiEntry:MyNetwork2,2". This can cause unintended behaviour, please use unique keys for every preference.
06-29 10:24:42.808   245   393 E Netd    : no such netId 123
06-29 10:24:42.832   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:45.737   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:48.754   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:50.442   413  4727 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:24:50.465   326   326 E wificond: NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN failed: Device or resource busy
06-29 10:24:50.466   413   505 E WificondScannerImpl: Failed to start scan, freqs=null
06-29 10:24:50.469   413   501 E WifiScanRequestProxy: Scan failure received. reason: -1,description: Scan failed
06-29 10:24:50.523  1020  1754 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
06-29 10:24:50.836   413  4727 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:24:50.865   413   505 E WificondScannerImpl: Failed to start scan, freqs=null
06-29 10:24:50.869   413   501 E WifiScanRequestProxy: Scan failure received. reason: -1,description: Scan failed
06-29 10:24:50.933  1020  1754 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
06-29 10:24:51.767   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:50.864   326   326 E wificond: NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN failed: Device or resource busy
06-29 10:24:54.789   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:24:57.806   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:25:00.454   413  6577 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:25:00.716   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:25:00.844   413  6577 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:25:04.849   413  6577 E WifiThreadRunner: WifiThreadRunner.call() timed out!
06-29 10:25:04.849   413  6577 E WifiThreadRunner: java.lang.Throwable: Stack trace:
06-29 10:25:04.849   413  6577 E WifiThreadRunner:  at com.android.server.wifi.WifiThreadRunner.call(WifiThreadRunner.java:80)
06-29 10:25:04.849   413  6577 E WifiThreadRunner:  at com.android.server.wifi.WifiServiceImpl.startScan(WifiServiceImpl.java:497)
06-29 10:25:04.849   413  6577 E WifiThreadRunner:  at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub.onTransact(IWifiManager.java:718)
06-29 10:25:04.849   413  6577 E WifiThreadRunner:  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
06-29 10:25:04.849   413  6577 E WifiThreadRunner:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
06-29 10:25:05.967  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=37:XX:XX:XX:XX:e2 reason=3 locally_generated=1
06-29 10:25:05.970   413   433 I EthernetTracker: interfaceLinkStateChanged, iface: wlan0, up: false
06-29 10:25:05.971   326   326 I wificond: Regulatory domain changed
06-29 10:25:05.973   413  3531 D WifiNl80211Manager: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:25:05.973   413  3531 D WifiNative: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:25:05.980   413   501 W LastMileLogger: Failed to stop event tracing: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/instances/wifi/tracing_on: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-29 10:25:05.982   413   501 W LastMileLogger: Failed to read event trace: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/instances/wifi/trace
06-29 10:25:05.985   326   326 I wificond: 2.4Ghz frequencies: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
06-29 10:25:05.987   326   326 I wificond: 5Ghz non-DFS frequencies:
06-29 10:25:05.987   326   326 I wificond: 5Ghz DFS frequencies:
06-29 10:25:05.987   326   326 I wificond: 6Ghz frequencies:
06-29 10:25:05.987   326   326 I wificond: Regulatory domain changed to country: ES
06-29 10:25:05.989   413   501 D WifiCountryCode: Reading country code from telephony
06-29 10:25:05.989  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
06-29 10:25:05.992   413   501 D WifiCountryCode: Set telephony country code to: 
06-29 10:25:05.992   326   326 I wificond: 2.4Ghz frequencies: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
06-29 10:25:05.993   326   326 I wificond: 5Ghz non-DFS frequencies:
06-29 10:25:05.993   413   501 D WifiCountryCode: updateCountryCode to null
06-29 10:25:05.993   326   326 I wificond: 5Ghz DFS frequencies:
06-29 10:25:05.993   326   326 I wificond: 6Ghz frequencies:
06-29 10:25:05.993   413   501 D WifiClientModeImpl: Start Disconnecting Watchdog 24
06-29 10:25:05.994  3892  3892 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=ES
06-29 10:25:05.999   413   501 I WifiClientModeImpl: Keep PMK cache for network disconnection reason 3
06-29 10:25:06.001   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: stopRssiMonitoring(l.2100) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE, .description = }
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   505 D WificondScannerImpl: Filtering out 1 scan results.
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: stopIpClient IpClientWithPreConnection: false
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: java.lang.Throwable
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.stopIpClient(ClientModeImpl.java:1069)
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.stopDhcpSetup(ClientModeImpl.java:1084)
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.handleNetworkDisconnect(ClientModeImpl.java:2761)
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.access$5400(ClientModeImpl.java:163)
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl$ConnectModeState.processMessage(ClientModeImpl.java:4290)
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:992)
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:809)
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
06-29 10:25:06.007   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
06-29 10:25:06.021   413   506 D ConnectivityService: [123 WIFI] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from UNKNOWN to DISCONNECTED
06-29 10:25:06.021   413   506 D ConnectivityService: [123 WIFI] disconnected, was satisfying 0
06-29 10:25:06.029   413   501 I WifiClientModeImpl: disconnectedstate enter
06-29 10:25:06.035   413   501 E WifiScoringParams: Invalid frequency(-1), using 5G as default rssi array
06-29 10:25:06.040  1020  1754 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: stopIpClient IpClientWithPreConnection: false
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl: java.lang.Throwable
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.stopIpClient(ClientModeImpl.java:1069)
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl.access$4200(ClientModeImpl.java:163)
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.server.wifi.ClientModeImpl$DisconnectedState.processMessage(ClientModeImpl.java:5686)
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:992)
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at com.android.wifi.x.com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:809)
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 V WifiClientModeImpl:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
06-29 10:25:06.042   413   501 I WifiClientModeImpl: Keep PMK cache for network disconnection reason 3
06-29 10:25:06.049   413   501 D WifiNetworkAgent: NetworkAgent: NetworkAgent channel lost
06-29 10:25:06.055   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:25:06.073   413   506 D ConnectivityService: NetReassign [no changes]
06-29 10:25:06.137  1020  1754 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
06-29 10:25:07.389   413  4727 D WifiNl80211Manager: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:25:07.389   413  4727 D WifiNative: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:25:07.411   413   505 D WificondScannerImpl: Filtering out 5 scan results.
06-29 10:25:07.425   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:25:07.461  1020  1754 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
06-29 10:25:10.475   413  4727 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:25:11.845   413  4727 D WifiNl80211Manager: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:25:11.845   413  4727 D WifiNative: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:25:11.860   413   505 D WificondScannerImpl: Filtering out 2 scan results.
06-29 10:25:11.872   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:25:11.926  1020  1754 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
06-29 10:25:14.866   413  4727 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
06-29 10:25:16.043   413   501 D WifiConfigStore: Writing to stores completed in 13 ms.
06-29 10:25:16.251   413  3531 D WifiNl80211Manager: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:25:16.251   413  3531 D WifiNative: Scan result ready event
06-29 10:25:16.267   413   505 D WificondScannerImpl: Filtering out 3 scan results.
06-29 10:25:16.279   413   501 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
06-29 10:25:16.343  1020  1178 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
```

I am unable to make sense of the above logs. They are nothing short of gibberish to an end-user trying to debug their problem.

So, would anyone have an idea about what is wrong here - and what should I do to get WiFi connection with this tablet on this router and network work?

Comment: The router screenshot shows that you have enabled WPA +WPA2 in "security options". Besides the fact that this is insecure and totally unnecessary as every device released in the last 15 years support WPA2 it is exactly the problematic situation you quoted in your question.

Comment: Thanks @Robert - well, the network was originally in WPA2-Personal [AES] only, and it didn't work - which is why at first, I took the advice of the linked article and enabled both, which again did not help. My guess is, the tablet is incapable of handling 5 GHz, and that was apparently the problem - once I set the WIFi to 2.4 GHz only and WPA2-Personal [AES] only, then it could connect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I found https://f-droid.org/packages/com.vrem.wifianalyzer/ - obviously, it had to be installed via `adb install` over USB, as I did not have WiFi.

But this program showed, that all this device can see, are networks in the 2.4 GHz range. So, I set my network to 5 GHz only - and suddenly, it was invisible to the tablet.

Then I thought, I should take a closer look at the specs of the tablet. Of course, there are no specs of the tablet to find easily.

Thankfully, I finally found something that looks more or less reasonable:

https://mobilespecs.net/tablet/THOMSON/Thomson_TEO_13P_T13P2BK32V2_32_GB_13.3_T13P2BK32V3.html

> - Processor model: A133
> - Processor family: Allwinner
> - Wi-Fi standards: 802.11b, 802.11g, Wi-Fi 4 (802.11n)
> - Top Wi-Fi standard: Wi-Fi 4 (802.11n)

Rather unfortunate (though expected), there is no mention of what WiFi chipset is being used; I found this: https://www.cnx-software.com/2020/10/31/allwinner-a133-tablet-processor-pairs-with-xr829-or-aw859a-wifi-bluetooth-chip/

> the company also pairs A133 processor with its own wireless chips, either XR829 WiFI 4 and Bluetooth 4.2 chip, or AW859A dual-band 802.11ac WiFi 5 and Bluetooth 5 chip.

So, my guess is this device has an XR829 WiFi chipset. But never mind that.

If I look at https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/difference-between-wifi-6-and-wifi-5.html - they mention that WiFi 3 "supports 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz frequency bands", but there is no such mention for WiFi 4. So, I cannot really tell, if WiFi 4 *in principle* supports 5 GHz - but based on what the app above reported, I assumed that this WiFi chip cannot handle 5 GHz.

So, I just made these changes to my WiFi network, with respect to the screenshot posted above in OP:

- Security options: back to WPA2-Personal [AES] *only*
- Band: 2.4 GHz *only*

... and finally, it connected to the Wi-Fi.